# jQuery find li with class until

Tags: php, jquery

This might be tricky.

Php will generate:

```
<li>element</li>
<li>element</li>
<li class="alt">element</li>
<li class="alt">element</li>
<li class="alt">element</li>
<li>element</li>
<li>element</li>
<li class="alt">element</li>
<li class="alt">element</li>
<li class="alt">element</li>
<li>element</li>
```

What I need is a way to find the li elements with the .alt class until the li elements start.
So...

```
<li>element</li>
<li>element</li> // if I click on this one, it will select
<li class="alt">element</li> // this one
<li class="alt">element</li> // and this one
<li class="alt">element</li> // and this one
<li>element</li> // stops selecting here
<li>element</li>
<li class="alt">element</li> // doe not this one
<li class="alt">element</li> // or this one
<li class="alt">element</li> // or any other .alt
<li>element</li>
```

I tried doing this with .find(), but I can't find a way to divide the .alt elements into groups and isolate the first one.

Any braniacs there with a good idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using jquery 1.4 you can use the new nextUntil method.

http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/

**edit - example:**

```
$("li").click(function() {

   $(this).nextUntil("li[class='']").each(function() {           
    console.log($(this));           
   });

});
```

Comment: I just read about this the other day. Me and my memory, thank you very much mate.

Comment: @daulex - no problem
@mark - yes, this method is quite a handy one. I can think of many cases where I could have used it before. I also enjoy the more intuitive .index() usage.

Answer (score 0):

try (couple of edits but think I have it)

$('li:contains(element)').click().find('li:contains(element):not[alt]:first').prevAll('li.alt');

Answer (score 0):

couldn't you add an extra class for the lis thats gonna be retrieved?